# I want multiple Three.js animations inside my html, but they are overlapping

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm professional graphicdesigner and have problem with Three.js

[image]

I have try many things, but this not good. I just duplicated the imported model and renamed it. I try everything on the interwebs. This works, but they overlap, I also have 2 different names. Here is my .js

```
var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 4;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 4;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
                // important for multiple canvasuse
container = document.getElementById( 'container1' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
                    // cam
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 4;
                    // scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    // light
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                scene.add( ambient );
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );
                    // BG
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
                    // BEGIN Clara.io JSON loader code
                var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                objectLoader.load("untitled-scene.json", function ( obj ) {
                    scene.add( obj );
                } );
                    // mlg render
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( 400, 200 );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                        // resize?
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                }
                    // draw a different, next canvas
container = document.getElementById( 'container2' );
document.body.appendChild( container );

                    // cam
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 4;
                    // scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    // light
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                scene.add( ambient );
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );
                    // BG
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

                // BEGIN Clara.io JSON loader code
                var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                objectLoader.load("untitled-scene2.json", function ( obj ) {
                    scene.add( obj );
                } );
                // mlg rendere reloaded
                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setSize( 400, 200 );
                    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                //
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


            function onWindowResize() {
                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( canvas_width, canvas_height );
            }
            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 16;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 16;
            }
            //
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }
            function render() {
                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .03;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .03;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
```

and here ma html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>farts</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #808080;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;

                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #info {
                color: #00f;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }

            #container1 {
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 5px solid red;
                float:left;
                margin-top: 200px;
            }
            #container2 {
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                float:left;
            }



        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
farts <br />
        </div>
        <div id="container1">
        <script src="num1.js"></script><br/>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="stats.min.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div id="container2">
        <script src="num1.js"></script><br/>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="stats.min.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's just a fun project, but I have love to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
renderer.setSize( 400, 200 );
```

for:

```
renderer.setSize( 300, 200 );
```

Because your div has the dimensions (300,200) and you send it to render other dimensions (400,200), that's why your canvas comes out of your div and with that you should not have problems editing your css.